# Total Acumulado 12, 6 e 3 meses

Tags: powerbi, dax

Preciso inserir abaixo do meu total, um total acumulado de 12,6 e 3 meses. A base que utilizo contém uma coluna chamada competencia para agrupar.

Eu na verdade criei mais uma tabela para colocar essas 3 linhas de acumulado, no entanto não consigo ocultar os cabeçalhos dessa tabela.

Não sei se consigo resolver isto através de variáveis com aluga função DAX.

Abaixo está como gostaria que fosse o resultado:

[image: Tabela com total acumulado]

Comment: Paulo talvez o ideal seja criar novas colunas calculadas com essas instruções ( 12,6 e 3 meses) e coloca-lás em linha, assim voce consegue o subtotal por nível e o totalizador geral.

Comment: Utilizei cartões abaixo da tabela e deu. Obrigado.